# Internet Explorer 11 website scales everything (with native scroll) to enormous size

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, browser, internet-explorer-11

I am working on Ionic v1 application. It looks good on Android, iOS devices and most of the browsers, including MS edge. I needed to add `Object.assign` polyfill for it to start on IE11 but it's starting now.

But the website is scaled, big, everything is enormous, ever scrollbars are enormous. On my laptop is 15" Windows 10 Home edition it looks like this:

[image]

I've checked:

1. Browser zoom is 100%
2. HTML meta tags are as following:

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
> ```

altering them doesn't change anything.

3. Some dimensions are in `rem`, but hanging `<html>` `font-size` from `100%` to `62%` or `16px` doesn't considerably influence anything.
4. Interestingly for some reason `window.devicePixelRatio` is 4 and something on Asus PC.
5. I've tried adding full `core-js` polyfill library, but that didn't change anything.

**N.B.**: It turned out that Ionic that I've created this website with doesn't support IE. **Nevertheless, in the past I haven't seen such issues when something was not supported, e.g. with native scroll exploding to such dimensions.**

**Question:** What can cause this effect?

Comment: Not sure what causes this (as I have encountered this a lot of times), but if I were you, I'd really make users feel guilty for using IE in the first place. `:P`

Comment: I agree with @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, anyway [Ionic does not support IE](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support/), there might be further trouble...